# Toggling boolean state in React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

When I run the following code and clicking the button, I manage to trigger the useEffect function:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const Example = () => {
  const [bool, setBool] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(bool);
  }, [bool]);

  return (
    <button
      type='button'
      onClick={() => {
        setBool(!bool);
        setBool(!bool);
      }}
    >
      Check
    </button>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  root
)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

However, when I write:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const Example = () => {
  const [bool, setBool] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(bool);
  }, [bool]);

  return (
    <button
      type='button'
      onClick={() => {
        setBool(true);
        setBool(false);
      }}
    >
      Check
    </button>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  root
)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

I understand that the useEffect function isn't triggered as setBool is async, and React merges these changes so the final state wasn't changed (bool remains false).

My question is, why React is unable to detect it in the case of !bool & !bool that I showed up.

Thanks

Comment: Your first example is equivalent to either "setBool(false); setBool(false);" or "setBool(true); setBool(true);". The onclick uses the stale/old value of bool both times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case, you are taking the *current* value of `bool` (whatever that value may be) and negating it before setting it in the state. As a result, state is changed, so `useEffect` is triggered.

In the second case, you are providing a hard-coded value. If the value of `bool` is already `false`, then `setBool(false)` won't have any affect on the state; as a result, `useEffect` won't be triggered.